# C++17 Is it legal to use a typedef'd type in definition bit not declaration?

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

This has come up in a code review of more complex code so I'll ask a generic question here :-

Using C++17 here if it matters.

Assume you have a **class MyType** with some definition.
Assume you have something like "

```
using MyTypePtr = std::shared_ptr<MyType>
```

In a header file you have a function :-

```
void myFunc(std::shared_ptr<MyType> ptr);
```

And then in the implementation in another file you have :-

```
void myFunc(MyTypePtr ptr)
{
}
```

Is this legal in C++? The compiler (msvc & gcc) don't complain and it seems to *work*, but I'm not sure if the One Definition Rule or something similar applies here? Both definitions have the same types but via a different series of tokens? Does that matter in this context?

Comment: As long as the using statement is in a header file it should be ok. But also do not forget to put your code in a namespace.

Comment: You create an *alias* of a type. And that alias can be used to instead of the real type, but it's still the exact same type as what it's an alias of.

Comment: If I remeber right "same sequence of tokens" had an amendmend regadring aliases. Typically as codereivew goes, I would question  why it was done here. It needs a purpose or it should be fixed one way or another. one possible purpose is that .cpp file  is a shared code compiled with different sets of definitions (e.g. with some generated headers), where `MyTypePtr` may mean different things

Comment: @PepijnKramer Why should the `using` statement be in the header? There is certainly no requirement for that. So, is it just for code hygiene?

Comment: @j6t What if the alias needs to be used from multiple source files? If it's in a header file, then it's the same for all source files that include that header file, and it's written in only one place. But you're right, there's no requirement to put it in a header file, though it is a good idea.

Comment: @j6t It should share at least the same header file as the header file where the declaration for myFunc is. If there are more header files depending on the type alias it is better to have it in a header file of its own. And otherwise it is good code hygiene... one class/type per header as a rule of thumb (just be smart about it)